# Convert an h264 byte string to OpenCV images

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, stream, h.264

In Python, how do I convert an h264 byte string to images OpenCV can read, only keeping the latest image?

Long version:

Hi everyone.

Working in Python, I'm trying to get the output from adb screenrecord piped in a way that allows me to capture a frame whenever I need it and use it with OpenCV. As I understand, I need to constantly read the stream because it's h264.

I've tried multiple things to get it working and concluded that I needed to ask for specific help.

The following gets me the stream I need and works very well when I print stream.stdout.read(n).

```
import subprocess as sp

adbCmd = ['adb', 'exec-out', 'screenrecord', '--output-format=h264', '-']
stream = sp.Popen(adbCmd, stdout = sp.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
```

Universal newlines was necessary to get it to work on Windows.

Doing:

```
sp.call(['ffplay', '-'], stdin = stream.stdout, universal_newlines = True)
```

Works.

The problem is I am now trying to use ffmpeg to take the input h264 stream and output as many frames as possible, overwriting the last frame if needed.

```
ffmpegCmd = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24', '-vcodec', 'h264', 'fps=30', '-']
ffmpeg = sp.Popen(ffmpegCmd, stdin = stream.stdout, stdout = sp.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
```

This is what I think should be used, but I always get the error "Output file #0 does not contain any stream".

Edit:

### Final Answer

Turns out the universal_newlines option was ruining the line endings and gradually corrupting the output. Also, the ffmpeg command was wrong, see LordNeckbeard's answer.

Here's the correct ffmpeg command to achieve what was used:

```
ffmpegCmd = ['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'bmp', '-vf', 'fps=5', '-']
ffmpeg = sp.Popen(ffmpegCmd, stdin = stream.stdout, stdout = sp.PIPE)
```

And then to convert the result into an OpenCV image, you do the following:

```
fileSizeBytes = ffmpeg.stdout.read(6)
fileSize = 0
for i in xrange(4):
    fileSize += fileSizeBytes[i + 2] * 256 ** i
bmpData = fileSizeBytes + ffmpeg.stdout.read(fileSize - 6)
image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(bmpData, dtype = np.uint8), 1)
```

This will get every single frame of a stream as an OpenCV image.

Comment: What's the actual `ffmpeg` command being executed by the script? The complete `ffmpeg` console output/log will be informative as well. Does `ffmpeg` work if you run it manually, unscripted?

Comment: The ffmpeg command is the contents of ffmpegCmd string array in the last snippet of code.

Comment: I asked because `ffmpeg -f image2pipe -pix_fmt bgr24 -vcodec h264 fps=30 -` is not a valid command. For outputting images from a pipe input I would expect something more like `ffmpeg <input options> -i - output_%03d.png`

Comment: Well yeah, I figured from the errors. What would be the right ffmpeg command to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm trying to get the stream from stdin and output images (bgr24 format if possible) to stdout as long as they come in. I figured out -i pipe: for the stdin, now I just need to figure out the stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of these:

```
ffmpeg -i - -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo -
ffmpeg -i pipe: -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo pipe:
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -pix_fmt bgr24 -f rawvideo pipe:1
```

- You didn't provide much info about your input so you may need to add additional input options.
- You didn't specify your desired output format so I just chose rawvideo. You can see a list of supported output formats (muxers) with `ffmpeg -muxers` (or `ffmpeg -formats` if your `ffmpeg` is outdated). Not all are suitable for piping, such as MP4.
- See [FFmpeg Protocols: pipe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe).

Comment: Those all worked, but I ended up adding -vcodec bmp and -vf fps=5 for a final command: `ffmpeg -i - -f rawvideo -vcodec bmp -vf fps=5 -`. For the cv2 part, I used the BMP headers to automatically find the resolution and frame size and read the appropriate amount of bytes from the stdout and cv2.imdecode it, since it's a standard BMP.

Comment: @FredDufresne Good to hear you found a solution that works for you. Note that forcing a frame rate may result in dropped or duplicated frames id it varies from the input.

Answer (score 0):

It works well just a minor changes:
This will read the stream in a loop and show each time the last image

```
adbCmd = ['adb', 'exec-out', 'screenrecord', '--output-format=h264', '-']
stream = sp.Popen(adbCmd, stdout = sp.PIPE)

ffmpegCmd =['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vf', 'scale=324:576', 
'-vcodec', 'bmp',  '-']
ffmpeg = sp.Popen(ffmpegCmd, stdin = stream.stdout, stdout = sp.PIPE)

while True:
    fileSizeBytes = ffmpeg.stdout.read(6)
    fileSize = 0
    for i in xrange(4):
        fileSize += array.array('B',fileSizeBytes[i + 2])[0] * 256 ** i
    bmpData = fileSizeBytes + ffmpeg.stdout.read(fileSize - 6)
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(bmpData, dtype = np.uint8), 1)
    cv2.imshow("im",image) 
    cv2.waitKey(25)
```