# adb screen streaming to python + opencv

Tags: python, opencv, adb

I know add can record screen and take screen shots. Is is possible to capture a live stream of the screen with any of these commands?

Would it be possible, for instance, to make a 10fps streaming with `adb shell screencap` directly, without any other app?

I've tried this, but it returns "pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input"

`adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | ffplay -`

Comment: Yes. Just edited. I'm trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983331/convert-an-h264-byte-string-to-opencv-images

But I'm not even being able to stream to ffplay in the first place..